# deploying java war file in windows server R2 enterprise 2008

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, jboss, web-deployment

I need to deploy Java web application war file in a server (windows server R2 enterprise 2008). This server is in my organization in a local area network with known IP. I need to deploy my web application war file in this server. I am open to use jboss or apache tomcat in this server and configure so that my application is accessible through [ip-address]/application url across local area network. Please guide me, am sorry if i sound too naive.

Tomcat 8 or jboss 7. Please help.

Comment: (1) You need to provide a pattern in your deployment descriptor file. (2) What is the version of you JBoss server? Based on the version, deployment steps can be stated.

Comment: Tomcat 8 or jboss 7.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, you are using JBoss 7.x or Tomcat 8.x. For JBoss Server, you need to copy your .war on the following location:

**${jboss.server.base.dir}/standalone/deployments/**

Now if your server is already running then it will be deployed automatically otherwise you just need to start the server.

For Tomcat Server, you need to copy your wat file in your appBase and the default location of appBase is given below:

**$CATALINA_BASE/webapps**

This [link](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/deployer-howto.html) will help you for JBoss Deployment and this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server) will help you for Tomcat Deployment